# Getting System Info with C# Console Application

Tags: c#

I want to get system info with c# console app. Actually cmd is gives system info but i want to make myself program and learning.

Comment: You can start learning by research and reaching.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? What info you refer to and what did you try to get it?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I want to get system info like in cmd.

Comment: What specific system info? What command in cmd are you trying to replicate? Just pass that into google and you'll find your answer...

Comment: Like : systeminfo

Comment: You can invoke systeminfo command from c# code using `Process.Start`

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski But i want to get system info. I can just open a folder with `Process.Start`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use .NETs System.Diagnostic.Process class to replicate it**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        string output = "";
        var proc = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c systeminfo")
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32\"
        };
        Process p = Process.Start(proc);
        p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args1) => { output += args1.Data + Environment.NewLine; };
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine(output);

    }
```

[image]

Comment: happy to help, you can also mark the answer as resolved by clicking on the green tick box. Thanks